# Ruby. OOP. Attribute not stored?

Tags: ruby

What i bascially want is to extend the Numeric class so that it has one extra Attribute (currencie), which is set when of the undefined methods are invoked [yen(s), euro(s), etc.]
So, here is the class definition:

```
 class Numeric

 @@currencies = {'yen' => 0.013, 'euro' => 1.292, 'rupee' => 0.019, 'dollar' => 1}

 attr_accessor :currencie

 def method_missing(method_id)
   singular_currency = method_id.to_s.gsub( /s$/, '')
   if @@currencies.has_key?(singular_currency)
    self.currencie = singular_currency
    self * @@currencies[singular_currency]
    puts "method finished"
   else
    super
   end
 end

 def in(convert_to) 

 end

end
```

Now, when i run the code

```
a = 5.rupees
puts "currencie is -> " + a.currencie
```

i've got:

```
method finished
/path_to_file/hw2.1.rb:33:in `<main>': undefined method `currencie' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Also the attribute **currencie** seems to be unset.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `method_missing` should return object i.e. `self`. Just add `self` to `method_missing` and it will work.

```
def method_missing(method_id)
   singular_currency = method_id.to_s.gsub( /s$/, '')
   if @@currencies.has_key?(singular_currency)
    self.currencie = singular_currency        
    puts "method finished"
    self * @@currencies[singular_currency] # just change the order of expressions
   else
    super
   end
 end
```

EDIT: Fixed as `injekt` said

Comment: Wait, this is wrong. You want to return `self * @@currencies[singular_currency]` not unmodified `self`.. otherwise this makes the line above `puts` completely useless

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic. But that won't work either. You can't change the value of `self` in numeric. You just need to substitute the return `self` for the above code.

Comment: after some testing i figured out, the **method_missing** must have    'return self' at the end. otherwise the yet new object is returned, without "currencie" attribute just set.